# Exibir Tela de boas Vindas com nome do Usuário em pagina PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-select

Boa tarde. Estou tentando implementar em uma pagina **PHP** uma mensagem de boas vindas após um login. Gostaria de exibir o nome do usuário que acabou de logar através de uma variável **php**. A tela de login requer o email e a senha cadastrada no banco de dados. Armazenei cada um dos dois em uma **SESSION** para fazer a autenticação. Na pagina em seguinte como eu quero o **NOME**, sei que é necessário buscar este nome no banco de dados passando como parâmetro o email que o usuário se logou e armazenando em uma variável(consulta **mysql**). Tentei fazer assim:

```
 $busca = "SELECT Nome FROM newsletter WHERE Email = '$_SESSION['Email']'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $busca) or die("Falha");
```

O compilador retorna o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blog\php\areavip.php on line 14

Consegui contornar este erro pegando essa SESSION e armazenando em outra variável, deixando o código assim:

```
$email = $_SESSION['Email'];
$busca = "SELECT Nome FROM newsletter WHERE Email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $busca) or die("Falha");
```

O problema é quando usei um echo para exibir o que foi armazenado na variável ele retorna:

```
SELECT Nome FROM newsletter WHERE Email = 'usuario1@gmail.com'.
```

O email foi armazenado, mas ele retorna toda consulta como uma string. Antes de usar este comando eu testei ele no Workbench para ver se o retorno da busca era o esperado e lá ta tudo certo o problema esta em algum lugar deste script mas não consegui encontrar.

Answer (score -1):

Josafa será que você pode postar o código que você está usando para dar `echo`? Você precisa fazer algo assim:

```
$email   = $_SESSION['Email'];
$busca   = "SELECT Nome FROM newsletter WHERE Email = '$email'";
$result  = mysqli_query($conexao, $busca) or die("Falha");    
$row     = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['Nome'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde Lucas, muito obrigado pela sua resposta, ja achei o erro que cometi, eu esqueci de usar a função array fetch. Depois de declarar a variavel $result e ja escrevi 
echo $busca , por isso tava retornado tudo como uma string. Ja consegui arrumar meu código aqui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.